# Seeking the name of an animated sci-fi film about a world mined to the point of collapse

Tags: movie, story-identification

I saw an animated film, perhaps a short, about a planet with two levels and two classes.  The surface level was enjoyed by a leisure class bent on using as much natural resource as possible.  The sub-level was inhabited by miners who built elaborate systems of reinforcement to keep the planet's crust from collapsing into the mined out core area.  I seem to remember warnings sent to the surface class, but it took disaster to jar them into stopping their over-consumption.  It ended with a "we stopped just in time" feel.

Comment: Any idea of how old the film is? Animation style? Theatrical/TV/Video?

Comment: Could it possibly be [Starchaser: The Legend of Orin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starchaser:_The_Legend_of_Orin)?

Comment: Hi Trish -  I watched the trailer for Starchaser: The Legend of Orin, and that's much more complex than the film I'm remembering.  And I'd guess the characters were more cartoony in appearance.

Comment: As for the age of the film, I would guess late 70's or early 80's.  I can't recall the animation style.  I watched it on TV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recall this short film from 1979: "Intergalactic Thanksgiving, or Please Don't Eat the Planet". The story concerns a stoic settler family that emigrates to a planet inhabited by giddy comedian creatures. The settler's young daughter befriends a local youth, and together they discover the disaster growing beneath the planet's surface.

[image]

Comment: Yes! This has to be it. I'll need to rewatch all the way through, but the image of the surface held up by an underground framework brings it all back. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.